# Is there a way to add a function call to a struct initialization?

Tags: c++

I'm internationalizing a console app using gettext, and would like to wrap all the strings in the following struct in `gettext()` calls.

Here is the header with the initialization:

```
#include <libintl.h>
#define _(STRING) gettext(STRING)

struct MinimalLoc {
    char name[40];
};

const struct MinimalLoc MINIMAL[1] = {
    {_("Пустыня")}
};
```

This is contained within the `data.hpp` header and fails upon `#include` to `main.cpp`, where `main()` is empty (return 0).

The issue is this returns the following error:

```
data.hpp:9:30: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
     #define _(STRING) gettext(STRING)
                       ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

Would be grateful for any pointers on where to look. I'm using this project to learn a bit more about C++, but unsure how to debug this.

**EDIT 12:38**
I've updated the above with a clear reproducible example (thanks Yksisarvinen). You may notice the error is different with this example -- `gettext()` expects `char*`, which is not in the initializer.

Comment: We need a [mcve] to help. It's perfectly valid to use functions in this context, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Using non ascii char in source file might be problematic (file encoding, compiler encoding, ...).

Comment: Your initializer does not match the struct definition(s). It has nothing to do with either `gettext` or your macro.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the comments all, updated the post with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @hal You say you are learning about C, but your question is tagged C++.  Which is it? They are separate languages with very different sets of rules

Comment: @RemyLebeau I work in C (firmware) and wish to expand on my C++, amended this in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot initialize char array (`char[40]`) from (const) char pointer (`const char*`) (which is the return type of `gettext`).

If possible, change `char name[40]` to `std::string name`.

Else, it cannot be done from initialization, and you have to copy the C-string into the char array afterward:

```
strncpy(name, _("Пустыня"), sizeof (name));
if (name[sizeof (name) - 1] != '\0') { // translation too long
    // error handling as throw.
    // or try to recover...

    // as minima, but might not be sufficient in middle of utf-8 character
    name[sizeof (name) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: using `std::string name` was what I was looking for, thanks :)